# How to Restore inApp purchase in Android?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

How do I restore inApp purchase if the user has already bought the app?

The problem is that if a user first purchases then uninstalls the app then re-installs the app, the user must have to buy that product again.

Answer (score 0):

InApp purchases made for Managed products is always managed by google. 
Once a user buys it, it remains in his purchase list unless it is consumed by making InApp SDK API consume call. 
So make the inapp products as Managed product and restore the purchases by making getPurchases() call. Even if the payment dialog is invoked it will show "User already own this item".